# Derivation of laws using proportionality

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When deriving physical laws I always find that there's this one step I don't understand. It seems so straight forward but I don't get it.
Assume that $y$ depends on two variables $x$ and $z$. varies linearly with $x$ (if $z$ is kept constant) that is $y=cx$, and, also, $y=mz$ (if $x$ is kept constant).
My question is, from the previous information, why is it true that $y=k x \cdot  z$ where $k$ is some constant?

I didn't find the tag; proportionality so I chose the closest one.

Answer (score 0):

If $y = cx$ whenever $z$ is a constant, then the only part of this equation that varies with $z$ is the coefficient $c$. Ergo we can write: $$y = c(z) x$$ for some function $c$. Similarly, we have $$y = k(x) z$$ by the other assumption. Take the derivative with respect to $x$, we get $$c(z) = k'(x) z \implies k'(x) = c(z)/z$$ - but this must be true for all $x,z$, so we have that both sides are constants - and hence $k(x)$ is linear. The same argument works for $c(x)$.